# How to install latest Spotify testing version?

Tags: software-installation, spotify

The stable Spotify client on Linux has not been updated for a while.

Is there a way to install the latest (testing) version which includes some new features ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Do not forget that this is a testing version, you may encounter bugs that do not occur in the stable version !**

---

Use the testing PPA of Spotify ([source and release notes](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-Community-Blog/Spotify-Client-1-x-beta-for-Linux-has-been-released/ba-p/1147084)):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D2C19886
echo deb http://repository.spotify.com testing non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

*Note : This version includes the `libgcrypt11` libraries which are missing in Ubuntu 15.04 & 15.10 and prevent Spotify to launch.*

[image]

Comment: Thanks brother! By your instruction I received this kind of program which I am used on Win7, now it finds my Yamaha amp :) Great! Note: version 1.0.17.75.g8f111100 runs 100% stable on my mint17.1 machine
And how nice is that?! I can create folders, as well <3 Ahhh, THANKS hg8, your tip is awesom!